# setState and setInterval cause "Warning: Can only update a mount or mounting component."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a strange problem with setState and setInterval. As I use them together the following waring come up:

> Warning: Can only update a mount or mounting component. This usually
>   means you called setState, replaceState or forceUpdate on an unmounted
>   component. This is a no-op.

This warning is fine in Android and it doesn't have any drawbacks there. However, in ISO it causes freeze in the App randomly!  Here is my code:

I have a button that whenever I touch it, it should make a modal on(true) and after 10 seconds it should make it off(false) and then redirect to another page. Here is the code of button:

```
 onPressEnter() {
    this.setState({ isModalVisible: true);
        if(this.timer > 0) return;
                    this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
                      //turn off the pop up
                      this.setState({ isModalVisible: false });
                      this.props.navigation.navigate('ParkInBuilding', {user: this.state.passedProps.user,  pState:this.state.passedProps.pState, pState: this.state.passedProps.pState, actSection: 'finalpage_2A'});
                      this.timer = null;  //not necessary if you are unmounting the component
                    }, 10000);
 }
```

In `render()` I have a modal as below:

```
          <Modal isVisible={this.state.isModalVisible}>
              <View style={styles.timerContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.orangeTextBold}>Si prega di passare il{"\n"}cancello di entrata.
              <Text style={styles.itemBold}>{"\n"} </Text>
              <Text style={styles.itemBold}>{"\n"}Benvenuto nel Parcheggio {this.state.parkingname}{"\n"}
              </Text> </Text>
              <Text style={styles.itemBold}> </Text>
               <CountdownCircle
                seconds={10}
                radius={40}
                borderWidth={8}
                color="#FABB00"
                bgColor="#fff"
                textStyle={{ fontSize: 30 }}
                onTimeElapsed={() => console.log('Elapsed!')}
              />
                </View>
              </Modal>
```

The button:

```
  <View style={ styles.buttonContainer } >
        <Button_yellow  style={styles.buttonW}  onPress={ this.onPressEnter.bind(this)}  label="              Entra              " icon="Mirino_giallo"  />
        </View>
```

The problem is that as I put `this.setState({ isModalVisible:  false});` into the `setTimeout()`, the mentioned waring comes randomly. (Sometimes I have it and the App freezes and sometimes it works fine)
Can you help me to solve this problem? It annoyed me for a week! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `setState` callback to navigate after updating the state :

```
this.setState({ isModalVisible: false }, () => this.props.navigation.navigate(...));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, let me test it.

Comment: I believe that the second argument to `setState` should be a function. In this case you're passing it the result of executing the `navigate` function instead.

Comment: I up-voted both of you. The warning has been disappeared but the freezing is still there! Do you have any idea?

Comment: You mean freezing with no errors and unable to continue without killing the app ?

Comment: Yes, with no warning and error. I tested it on many devices for several times. It becomes freeze! and as I remove it, it becomes fine again. :(

Comment: Anyway, the warning has been solved. Now, which answer should be selected as a correct answer for this questions? :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding explanation to Dyo answere :

setState actions are asynchronous and are batched for performance gains.

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value. There is no
>   guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may
>   be batched for performance gains.

In your case you may want to be certain that your navigation job will  be trigger at the end of your setState :

```
this.setState({ isModalVisible: false }, this.props.navigation.navigate(...));
```

Comment: I up-voted both of you. The warning has been disappeared but the freezing is still there! Do you have any idea?

Comment: Anyway, the warning has been solved. Now, which answer should be selected as a correct answer for this questions? :)